# In h2 db (client/server mode) during high load, 'Lob not found' exception occurs even if blob available

Tags: blob, h2

*See trace below*

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.h2.message.DbException: General error:     "java.lang.RuntimeException: Lob not found: 12603" [50000-181]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertToIOException(DbException.java:364)
    at org.h2.store.LobStorageRemoteInputStream.read(LobStorageRemoteInputStream.java:73)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2278)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2749)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:779)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:279)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.JdbcDelegate.dequeueImmediate(JdbcDelegate.java:214)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.h2.message.DbException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Lob     not found: 12603" [50000-181]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:283)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:629)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.readLob(SessionRemote.java:778)
    at org.h2.store.LobStorageRemoteInputStream.read(LobStorageRemoteInputStream.java:71)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Lob     not found: 12603" [50000-181]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convert(DbException.java:295)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:221)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:161)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Lob not found: 12603
    at org.h2.message.DbException.throwInternalError(DbException.java:242)
    at org.h2.store.LobStorageMap.getInputStream(LobStorageMap.java:236)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:454)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:159)
    ... 1 more
```

The blob exists. I have verified. This exception didn't occur after executing **SET MAX_LENGTH_INPLACE_LOB 2048** (Default value was 128). I assume after setting this property to a higher value, blobs less than 2048 size are getting stored as inline column. Thus it prevents exception. But any explanation about why the exception occurs in heavy load with the default value. If blobs are stored separate, why does h2 fail to retrieve them? (assuming this is the cause for exception)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
After some searching i found this [h2-lob-issue](https://github.com/bwaldvogel/h2-lob-issue) Github page which point on this issue.

So if you upgrade to 1.4.183 this issue is fixed.

btw. which version of h2 do you used?